# Tenho um ficheiro externo PHP e gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer ligação a um ficheiro HTML

Tags: php

Tenho um ficheiro HTML e disseram-me para colocar o código PHP que fosse utilizar num ficheiro exter PHP, isto é possível? Como ficaria o código para "chamar" o ficheiro PHP externo para o ficheiro HTML?

Comment: Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um exemplo do que pretende fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguma funções para incluir arquivos dentro de outros arquivos.

1. [require_once](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require-once.php)
2. [require](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require.php)
3. [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)
4. [include_one](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include-once.php)

o que você precisa fazer é usar as tags `php` dentro do arquivo `html` e usar estas funções, por exemplo:

```
<body>
    ...
    <?php include_once('outro_arquivo.php'); ?>
    ...
</body>
```

Lembre-se de incluir o caminho para o arquivo que deseja incluir, no exemplo acima eu assumi que o `outro_arquivo.php` esta na mesma pasta que o arquivo `html`, logo, se você precisar incluir o arquivo que esta em outra pasta faça da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php include_once('pasta/subpasta/arquivo.php');
```

**Para que isso funciona seu arquivo principal deixara de ser um html, pois para que o arquivo seja compilado com php ele necessita da extensão `.php`**